# CUDA C pow() function causing rounding errors with modf() and similar functionality

Tags: cuda

I am tracking indices across threads by adding the thread to some value that is being sorted:  `value + threadIdx.x*.001`.  This works (theoretically) because the values I am sorting are whole numbers, however they can be negative.

When I go to pull the decimal part I am running into rounding errors.  Specifically the decimal part calculates to `1.0` in some instances (-3.0 for instance).

Code to reproduce problem:

```
code ="""

/* CUDA's random number stuff */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 64
#define INDEX_BASE_10 .001

extern "C" {

__device__ double decimal_part_to_index(double value) {
  
  value = fabs(value);
  value -= (long)value;
  value *= 1000;
  
  //if (value > NUM_THREADS) {
  //  return 0;
  //}
  
  return value;

}/*DECIMAL PART TO INDEX*/


/****GLOBAL****GLOBAL****GLOBAL****/
/*********GLOBAL****GLOBAL*********/
__global__ void foo(double *input_array,
                    double *result_array) {

  bool bool_array[2] = {0,1};

  int some_int = 3;
  
  input_array[threadIdx.x] = pow(some_int,1) + threadIdx.x*.INDEX_BASE_10;

  result_array[threadIdx.x] = decimal_part_to_index(input_array[threadIdx.x]);
  


}
}
"""
mod = SourceModule(code, no_extern_c=True)
foo = mod.get_function("foo")


GPU_result_1 = gpuarray.zeros(64, dtype=numpy.double)

GPU_result_2 = gpuarray.zeros(64, dtype=numpy.double)

for i in range(1):
    foo(GPU_result_1,
    GPU_result_2,
    block=(64,1,1), grid=(1,1,1))
```

As suggested in the comments the misuse of `pow()` with `int,int` arguments is a likely culprit.

ORIGINAL POST BELOW:

```
__device__ double decimal_part_to_index(double value) {
  
  value = abs(value);
  value -= (long)value;
  value *= 1000;
  
  //This catches rounding error for NUM_THREADS = 256
  //When value = -3.0, value -= (long)value is 1.0???
  if (value > NUM_THREADS) {
    return 0;
  }
  
  return value;

}/*DECIMAL PART TO INDEX*/
```

I also tried `modf()` with similar results but more instances of rounding error that I had to catch.  My question is will the above approach work for larger values of `NUM_THREADS` or will I encounter more instances of rounding that I have to catch?  For instance are there other values for which the above approach will give a decimal part of 1.0 that would break my scheme?  In my case the integer part is usually small but can get large. Is there any solution to safely take the decimal part?  It seems that no matter what I attempt I get similar issues with rounding.

EDIT: Output examples dividing and multiplying by 64:  `NUM_THREADS = 64`

In this first example, the second position shows -3.0 evaluated to 64, but should have evaluated to 0.  So we have to catch and set to 0.

```
array([ 2.359375, -3.      , -3.015625, -3.03125 , -3.046875, -3.0625  ,
       -3.078125, -3.09375 , -3.109375, -3.125   , -3.140625, -3.15625 ,
       -3.171875, -3.1875  , -3.203125, -3.21875 , -3.234375, -3.25    ,
       -3.265625, -3.28125 , -3.296875, -3.3125  , -3.328125, -3.34375 ,
       -3.375   , -3.390625, -3.40625 , -3.421875, -3.4375  , -3.453125,
       -3.46875 , -3.484375, -3.5     , -3.515625, -3.53125 , -3.546875,
       -3.5625  , -3.578125, -3.59375 , -3.609375, -3.625   , -3.640625,
       -3.65625 , -3.671875, -3.6875  , -3.703125, -3.71875 , -3.734375,
       -3.75    , -3.765625, -3.78125 , -3.796875, -3.8125  , -3.828125,
       -3.84375 , -3.859375, -3.875   , -3.890625, -3.90625 , -3.921875,
       -3.9375  , -3.953125, -3.96875 , -3.984375])

array([23., 64.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.,
       12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 24., 25.,
       26., 27., 28., 29., 30., 31., 32., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37., 38.,
       39., 40., 41., 42., 43., 44., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51.,
       52., 53., 54., 55., 56., 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62., 63.])
```

In this second example, the first position shows -2.0 evaluated to 0 like expected.

```
array([-2.      , -2.140625, -2.203125, -2.4375  , -2.46875 , -2.5     ,
       -2.6875  , -3.015625, -3.03125 , -3.046875, -3.0625  , -3.078125,
       -3.09375 , -3.109375, -3.125   , -3.15625 , -3.171875, -3.1875  ,
       -3.21875 , -3.234375, -3.25    , -3.265625, -3.28125 , -3.296875,
       -3.3125  , -3.328125, -3.34375 , -3.359375, -3.375   , -3.390625,
       -3.40625 , -3.421875, -3.453125, -3.484375, -3.515625, -3.53125 ,
       -3.546875, -3.5625  , -3.578125, -3.59375 , -3.609375, -3.625   ,
       -3.640625, -3.65625 , -3.671875, -3.703125, -3.71875 , -3.734375,
       -3.75    , -3.765625, -3.78125 , -3.796875, -3.8125  , -3.828125,
       -3.84375 , -3.859375, -3.875   , -3.890625, -3.90625 , -3.921875,
       -3.9375  , -3.953125, -3.96875 , -3.984375])

array([ 0.,  9., 13., 28., 30., 32., 44.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,
        7.,  8., 10., 11., 12., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21.,
       22., 23., 24., 25., 26., 27., 29., 31., 33., 34., 35., 36., 37.,
       38., 39., 40., 41., 42., 43., 45., 46., 47., 48., 49., 50., 51.,
       52., 53., 54., 55., 56., 57., 58., 59., 60., 61., 62., 63.])
```

Comment: CUDA floating-point numbers do not have decimal parts. They use base two, so they have binary parts. Divide and multiply by 2^8 (256) instead of 10^3 (1000) and all the rounding errors will vanish, as long as the original values have magnitudes under 2^(53−8).

Comment: Also, note that what Eric has written isn't just for CUDA floating-point numbers: it's for the binary floating-point numbers used on virtually all processors.

Comment: Using 2^8 yields the same problem for value = -3.0.  value -= (long)value is 1.0 even after taking the absolute value.  This solution DOES works for value = 2.0 (and same with base 10 transformation).  I don't understand precision floating points enough to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: I tried your code (on a conventional CPU, not a GPU).  Both 2.359375 and -3.0 work fine.  I did have to change the `abs()` call in `decimal_part_to_index()` to `fabs()` after my compiler helpfully reminded me that `abs` is for ints.

Comment: Re "the second position shows -3.0 evaluated to 64": Cannot reproduce. It would very much improve the question if it included a *minimal* but complete and self-contained (that is, readily buildable and runnable) code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SteveSummit I don't think the abs() matters.  The problem happens with 3.0 also.

Comment: GPU floating point tends to be slightly different.  For example, the floats and doubles on NVIDIA GPUs deliberately violate certain aspects of the IEEE-754 specification.  (The motivation is efficiency, of course).  I haven't heard of anything this weird — but then again, my experience with GPUs is not extensive.

Comment: As an experiment, you might try your code using `float` instead of `double` — AIUI, NVIDIA only relatively recently started supporting `double` at all.

Comment: @njuffa Thing is, this is GPU code he's asking about.  You're probably not going to be able to compile or run the exact code he's having the problem with. But, lefunction, I meant to ask, what happens if you strip off the `__device__` qualifier, and compile this code for your CPU, and try it there?

Comment: @SteveSummit CUDA is no different than any other programming language in that minimal complete examples are required to reproduce problems for which asker is seeking debugging assistance (a.k.a. "Code or it didn't happen"). I have two machines here with two different versions of CUDA, so should be able to repro easily. FWIW, CUDA uses IEEE-754 `binary32` for `float` and IEEE-754 `binary64` for `double`, so there is nothing unusual about floating-point types in CUDA.

Comment: @SteveSummit Re "NVIDIA only relatively recently started supporting double at all". Define "recently". The first GPU architecture with hardware support for `binary64` was `Compute Capability 1.3`, introduced in 2008. Given the fast progression of GPU architectures, that is so outdated, it is not even supported any more by any CUDA  version that shipped in the past few years,

Comment: @SteveSummit Re "NVIDIA GPUs deliberately violate certain aspects of the IEEE-754 specification." Main differences, that should have no impact on the present case: (1) rounding control is static (that is, part of each instruction). Superior to the standard for common applications like interval arithmetic. (2) Floating-point exceptions always deliver the IEEE-754 defined *masked* response (e.g. NaN, infinity, zero). Differences are not necessarily about efficiency (e.g. GPUs expend hardware to handle subnormals at full speed), but what makes the most sense in a massively parallel architecture.

Comment: @njuffa ok I added minimum code to reproduce the error.

Comment: @lefunction This code is not yet buildable as-is. Where is `main()` that calls the kernel? The repro case needs to be buildable and *runnable*. Side remark: What do the multiple calls to `pow()` do? That is very confusing based on the previous description. Please add comments.

Comment: @lefunction Please review the code:. I get an error: `identifier "pow<int, bool, (int)0> " is undefined in device code`. I used CUDA 11,1, what version of CUDA are you using and what compilation flags are you using when invoking `nvcc` ? Please add that information to the question. I thought the idea here is to add a fractional part of `(double) threadIdx.x / NUM_THREADS` to all inputs. Where is the corresponding code?

Comment: @njuffa you asked for minimum reproducible code.  The problem is that I am not getting the correct result for the index using the float part.  I suspect it is because of the gnarly part of the code, that is why I had to include that part since I couldn't reproduce the problem other wise.  The code works except for the float extraction part in one instance at least where some_int = 3.

Comment: @lefunction This is tagged CUDA. The code needs to be self-contained CUDA code for me to repro. I don't know what Jupyter is. I have a second machine with CUDA 9.2, so the version should not be problematic for repro. If I understood the original question correctly, all inputs are integers, although represented as `double`. Your idea is to add a fractional part `(double) threadIdx.x / NUM_THREADS` to each input, and later strip that fractional part again (and  to retrieve the thread number based on the fractional part). I am not seeing that reflected in the code as posted.

Comment: @njuffa I am using pycuda but I don't think that should make a difference.  I don't have it in C code except for the kernel.  You might not need the extern c part that.

Comment: @lefunction I don't use pycuda either. Building and running a *self-contained* repro case is OK. The moment answerers need to add their own scaffolding, they may deviate from what you have locally and repor mat not occur. The compilation problem seems to be due to `#define INDEX_BASE_2 pow(NUM_THREADS, -1)`. as `pow(int,int)` is not part of C++11 (or CUDA, best I know). And this is likely also the root cause of your observations. The output of `pow` is not guaranteed to be exact; it may be off by a few ulps. Use `(1.0 / NUM_THREADS)` instead. Avoid `pow()` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @njuffa likely problem is pow() using int arguments.  The math is correct and it works (on my compiler) but I caught an edge case.  I updated the example.  When I unroll the logic nested in the pow() statements it appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above CUDA kernel code changing:

```
int some_int = 3;
```

to:

```
double some_int = 3;
```

will solve the issue with `pow()` messing up pulling the decimal part.

In my case I was trying to use `pow()` functions to execute `if/else` logic to determine sign.  Unpacking the logic using `if/else` statements instead of `pow()` also cleared up the issue without having to change types or recast any integers.